# How can I write a mingw-make makefile on Windows?

Tags: windows, makefile, mingw, wxwidgets

I am new to using GNU make. I have a makefile as below:

```
CFLAGS = -c -I $(WXWIN)\include\

hello: main.o

main.o:main.cpp

    gcc -c main.cpp

clean:

    rm main.o
```

When I run make command in console it can't find the header file "wx/wx.h". Its location: `$(WXWIN)=D:\wxWidgets\`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your makefile as follows:

```
CFLAGS = -c -I $(WXWIN)\include

hello: main.o

main.o: main.cpp
    gcc $(CFLAGS) main.cpp

clean:
    rm main.o
```